# Cant login in to my server: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a server running ubuntu 12.04 on amazon ec2, I always login using ssh -i /pem.pem ubuntu@ip. Accidentally I erased ~/ directory, I logged out and now I am trying to enter but i get:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Stop your EC2 instance
2. Detach your root Volume (/dev/sda1) -- Assuming this is `Volume A`
3. Spin up a new EC2 instance of the same type.
4. Attach `Volume A` to that new instance as `/dev/sdf`
5. ssh connect to his new instance.
6. `mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf`
7. `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf`
8. `cp ~/.ssh to /mnt/xvdf/home//.
9. `chmod 700 /mnt/xvdf/home/<username>`
10. `chmod 600 /mnt/xvdf/home/<username>/authorized_keys`
11. Shutdown new instance
12. Detach `Volume A` on new instance
13. Reattach `Volume A` on /dev/sda1 on original instance.
14. Start original instance.

You should be able to login now.